# How to hide or show Field's Label?

Tags: theming, entities, 8

Is there any programming method to hide or show each Field's Label of custom content type in twig template files, regardless of fields `manage display` setting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Heres a little twig filter module that does just that: https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_field_value. If you study the code you can see how the filter works and deduce how it works programatically.

Answer (score 6):

Override the template for that specific field and don't print the label.

**field--field-thing.html.twig**

```
{% if multiple %}
  <div{{ attributes }}>
    {% for item in items %}
      <div{{ item.attributes }}>{{ item.content }}</div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
{% else %}
  {% for item in items %}
    <div{{ attributes }}>{{ item.content }}</div>
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Alternatively, you can preprocess the field and remove the label/change the display, but personally I would do it in the templates so later on the label could easily be added back in.

Comment: I think it is best to give a code example...

Comment: code example has been added